# Bibliographic entry for websites does not show up in the compiled document

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex

This is what I have at the top:

```
\usepackage{csquotes,hyperref,url}
\usepackage[style=mla,guessmedium=false]{biblatex}
```

This is the bibligraphic entry:

```
 @Misc{owlparagraph,
      author = {Dana Lynn Driscoll and Allen Brizee},
      title = {On Paragraphs},
      note = "[Web. 17 April. 2010.]",
      year = {2010},
      uhowpublished = "\url{http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/606/01/}"
}
```

The entry does not show up in the document after compiling it. If I remove `[style=mla,guessmedium=false]`, then the entry appears.

I must have the bibliography in MLA format.

Answer (score 4):

1. Use the entry `online` instead of `misc`
2. `biblatex` supports the field `url`
3. use the field `urldate`

The entry should look like this:

```
@ONLINE{owlparagraph,
author = {Dana Lynn Driscoll and Allen Brizee},
title = {On Paragraphs},
urldate = "2011-04-17",
year = {2010},
url = "http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/606/01/"
}
```

Comment: This too did not work. I am using Latext 2009 from Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: @nixnotwin: You should install TeX Live manual. Or do you have some problems with that?

Comment: I have to submit my report in few hours. So for the time being I will delete that web citation. By the weekend I will try to  install the new version of Latex.

Comment: @nixnotwin: In this case you can wrote everything in the `note` key.